# CSS, PHP: Image on top of image, different

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a school project, but I have a little css problem which i'm unable to solve myself. I tryed many ways with `display: inline-block;` and `position: absolute; and position: relative;` but I weren't able to figure it out. I hope you can help me:
As you can see in the snippet I have cards, and playerface's the playerface's are on the right height, etc. But I want them to come on top of every card.
Is there anyone who can help me?

```css
.card-color{
        position: relative;
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
 .card-img{
        position: relative;
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    .cardtype{
        position: absolute
    }
    .face16{
        position: absolute;
        top: 32px;
        right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylez.css">
<title>1</title>
<div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/gold1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/silver0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/silver0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/silver0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/silver1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/silver1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/silver1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/bronze1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/bronze1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/bronze1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/bronze1.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/bronze0.png'></div><div class='card-color'><img class='cardtype' src='http://jterweele.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/img/bronze1.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/176635-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/184941-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/146562-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/53612-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/186561-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/165229-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/189461-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/164859-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/45119-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/158626-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/8473-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/186153-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/178509-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/198784-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/186115-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/150516-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/156722-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/176550-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/163423-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/177604-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/204713-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/189271-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/205989-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/206113-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/196932-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/202053-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/196935-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/202811-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/216699-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/203747-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/199830-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/213418-large.png'></div><div class='card-img'><img class='face16' src='http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/224130-large.png'></div></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Julan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a positioned parent,

`position: absolute;` your cards and set the `top:` and `left:` property to `0px`.

also you cannot end your body content with `</head>` :)

Your HTML should be inside `<body>` tags.

http://jsbin.com/xucaza/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not set properly to do what you want in the best way possible. Also you have missing semicolons in your CSS code.

You should move the div with class `.card-img` inside the div with class `.card-color` foreach of them.

I've also made you a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2urt8wtf/1/. It needs a little CSS twitching from your part but is the solution.

> You have to know that position absolute always depends on position
>   relative. They won't work well one without each other.

Also, your div elements should be between the body tags and the head tags should sourround the `script` tag, the `meta` tag, `title` etc, instead of what you have now.